# Assign Tap to Grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I try to add my grid a tap handler:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF1F1F1F" Tap="OnTap">........</Grid>
```

and in `InitializeComponent();` i get this:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.UIElement.Tap'. [Line: 14 Position: 58]

    {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.UIElement.Tap'. [Line: 14 Position: 58]
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at *.NowPlayingPageControl.InitializeComponent()
   at *.NowPlayingPageControl..ctor()}
```

Comment: You should give people more information. What is your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same problem, What I did it in the XAMl page where the XamlParseException was thrown I checked all the tap event, in one of the Tap event handler I found that it is not navigating to the code behind.

Rest was OK. So I check the code behind and found that there was an ambiguity in referencing a .dll.

`GestureEventsArgs` is having an ambiguity in  the following references.

`System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs` and     `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs`

So I replace `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs` with `System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs`

Now its working fine. One thing I want point out here is after I installed Toolkit dll this happenned, otherwise my code was working fine until then. As already pointed out by @haxor.

Answer (score 1):

What is the signature for your Tap method in the code-behind file?  When I have this issue, I do the following:

- Go into the designer for the XAML
- Find the object where the Tap action is defined
- Delete the text containing the Tap method name
- Save the file
- Double-click the field so that the designer will create a new Tap method
- Compare the new stub method's signature to my old one
- If there's a difference, fix it in the original method, and remove the new method

In almost every case, I had screwed something up around the event arguments part of the method signature (most recently because of installing the Toolkit).